# Why is the time complexity for this O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am looking at this question:

> Let T(n) be the maximum stack depth of the following function, in terms of n.
>
> ```
> double foo (int n)
> {
>     int i;
>     double sum;
>     if (n == 0) 
>         return 1.0;
>     else {
>         sum = 0.0;
>         for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
>             sum += foo (i);
>         return sum;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Find T(n) = O(?)

The answer provided is O(n), but I calculated to be O(n!). I am not sure how to devise a solution for this.

Comment: ‘maximum stack depth’ is not the same as ‘time complexity’

Comment: The question is asking for a modified version of size complexity, not time complexity. The max depth this will go is n layers deep

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is stack depth referring to how many recursions it can happen down a single "recursion"? 

If they were to ask the time complexity, is my answer O(n!) valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack depth can be expressed as the maximum number of recursive calls down from a single recursion at some point. `foo(n)` calls `foo(0)`, `foo(1)`,`foo(2)`,..., `foo(n - 1)`. If you trace recursive calls from `foo(n-1)`, you'll see it calls `foo(n - 2)`. It goes like this until `f(0)` is called. Therefore **maximum** stack depth is `O(n)`. It's not `O(n!)`.

What about time complexity?

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + ... + T(1) + T(0)
T(1) calls T(0) 1 times.  (2^0)
T(2) calls T(0) 2 times.  (2^1)
T(3) calls T(0) 4 times. (from T(2) + T(1) + T(0))
T(4) calls T(0) 8 times.
T(5) calls T(0) 16 times. (2^4)
         ...
T(n-1) calls T(0) 2^(n-2) times.

In total T(0) is called [1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + 2^(n-2)] + 1 times.
```

It is equal to `2^(n-2) + 2^(n-2)`, which can be expressed as `2^n / 2`.
Therefore it has exponential time complexity, that is `O(2^n)`.